# JQuery Sync 2 Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to sync 2 input boxes.

```
$("#input_box_1").bind("keyup paste", function() {
    $("#input_box_2").val($(this).val());
});
```

The above works great but I need to do the same for a checkbox.

My question is...how do I modify the code for it to work with a checkbox?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to modify the `checked` property according to the value of that property on the first checkbox whenever the first checkbox changes (so we bind to the `change` event):

```
$("#checkbox1").change(function() {
    $("#checkbox2").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Note that you don't need to pass `this` into jQuery, you can just access the property of the raw DOM element, which is faster.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
$("#input_box_1").on("change", function() {
    $("#input_box_2").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr('checked')` instead of `val()`

```
$("#input_box_1").bind("keyup paste", function() {
    $("#input_box_2").attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
});
```